# Woocommerce filtering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, filtering, product

Can one of you please give me an hint,a plugin or the code to make a similar filtering system like on this site ?

https://lakehilltrackside.com/parts/29

Im interested in this feature http://pokit.org/get/?2baad3a14bfb40480d91e3893e157c42.jpg

So I need that Model, Year and Schematic to be layed out like that and to work like that with woo commerce groups, attributes or whatever works.

I hope that you can help me :)

Comment: Normally stack user should not expect a plugin suggestion, rather try to google, if you have tried and failed consider posting the code and describe  your problem, you will definitely get some response.

Answer (score 1):

You should use WP_Query with meta query. Since all the attritubes will be the product(post) metas.Please look into .
[WP_Query codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)